# how to implement code for display the alert message for every 5 minutes?

Tags: android

hi all how to implement code for display the alert message for every 5 minutes (i mean  for every 5 minutes we can able to see resent alert messages and previous alert message when we open the alert information list) so kindly help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                                            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
                                            PERIOD,pi);
PERIOD=300000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `AlarmManager` and set `BroadCastReciever.`. in `AlarmMananger` send Broadcast for every 5 minutes and in `onRecieve` method of reciever you can display the dialog.. the Other go is Putting the display dialog code in `for loop` and making the thread `sleep for 5` min but i don't think thats what you want...

Answer (score 1):

here is the e.g.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RepeatAlarm.class);

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmSetter.this,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setAlarm.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,sender);
```